# how to use scanf to read every word in a file.

Tags: c, scanf

In c code. I have an input file (called in) that is a mad-lib in the format, "I have really < adjective> eyes" (no spaces inside the <>) and I want to write a bool function that uses scanf to read every word and return true if the word begins with '<' (also called a token) How would I go about doing that? and yes I have to use scanf. Here is what I have right now but I do not think that it is completely right, so another question is, how do I know if my function is properly working.

```
/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken(char word[]) {
    char first;
    int firstindex;

    while (1) {

        scanf("%s", word);

        first = word[MAX_LEN];
        firstindex = (int)strlen(word); 

        if (first == '<') {
            printf("The token is: %s\n", first); 
            return true;  }

        else {
            return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `first = word[MAX_LEN];` no, that's not right. What do you want this line to do?

Comment: I also note you "self-deleted" your last question that was answered. What is your intent regarding this question? To get you started, remove `first` and `firstindex` completely. Then after validating `if (scanf ("%s", word) == 1)`, just check `if (*word == '<')`

Comment: just rephrase my question better. And I wanted that line to initiate first as the first character of the word.

Comment: how would I validate if(scanf ("%s", word) ==1) ? would  if (scanf("%s", word) == 1 && *word == 'v') work?

Comment: What kind of logic leads you into thinking that `word[MAX_LEN]` is the first character of the word?

Answer (score 5):

In the caller, `word` must be sufficienly sized to hold the largest word in your text (+3 chars, 2 for `<,>` and the *nul-termanting* character. You should pass the maximum length for `word` as a parameter to `istoken`, but since you are using `scanf`, you must hard-code the *field width* modifier to protect your array bounds. (that is one of the reasons `fgets` is recommended over `scanf` -- but you must use `scanf`). Don't skimp on buffer size for `word` in the caller. Something like the following should suffice in the caller (probably `main()` for you):

```
#define MAXC 1024
...
char word[MAXC] = "";
```

There is no need for `first` or `firstindex`. To check the first character in a string, all you need do is *dereference* the pointer. With that, it is simply a matter of:

```
/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken (char *word) {

    while (scanf("%1023s", word) == 1)  /* did a valid read take place? */
        if (*word == '<')               /* is 1st char '<' ? */
            return true;                /* return true */

    return false;                       /* out of words, return false */
}
```

(**note:** simply returning the token in `word` via the pointer parameter while returning `bool`, seems a bit of an awkward factoring of your code -- but it is doable. Also, if the token exceeds `1024` chars, including the *nul-terminating* char -- you will not have a complete token in `word` on function return)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**A Short Example Reading `stdin`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXC 1024

/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken (char *word) {

    while (scanf("%1023s", word) == 1)  /* did a valid read take place? */
        if (*word == '<')               /* is 1st char '<' ? */
            return true;                /* return true */

    return false;                       /* out of words, return false */
}

int main (void) {

    char word[MAXC] = "";

    if (istoken (word))
        printf ("found token: '%s'\n", word);
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no token found.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has <too> many fleas." | ./bin/scanftoken
found token: '<too>'
```

Last note: while you, as you propose in the comment below, can output the token from within `intoken`, e.g.

```
bool istoken(char word[]) {
    while (scanf("%100s", word) == 1) { 
        if (word[0] == '<') { 
            printf("the token is: %s\n", word); 
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That is generally something you want to avoid. Within your *program design* you want (as a goal) to separate your implementation (what your program does, computes, etc..) from Input/Output. That makes your code usable when called by more than one function that wants to output `printf("the token is: %s\n", word);`

While a bit uncommon, your `istoken` function that locates a token and returns `true/false` makes more sense if the caller then uses that return to determine what to do with the token in `word`. If you are just going to print it from inside `intoken` if a token is found, and then do nothing with the return in the caller, then why declare it as `bool` anyway -- you may as well just declare it as `void` if you are not using the return.

Like I said this is (a goal). You can factor your code any way you like as long as it is valid code. The use of `printf` within `istoken` is perfectly valid for temporary debugging purposes as well. (in fact that is one of the most helpful debugging tools you have, just sprinkle temporary `printf` statements throughout the logic path in your program to find out where you code works as intended and where the "train-falls-off-the-track" so to speak.

---

**Example with File I/O**

OK, we are finally getting to `'Z'` with this `'XY'` problem. Since, as I now understand, you have your text in a file (I have used `"myfile.txt"` for the input) and you want to read your inputfile in `istoken` and return `word` and `true/false` to `main()` and if `true` then write the token to your output file (I used "tokenfile.txt" before for my output file), then what you need to do is open both your input file and output file using `fopen` in `main()` similar to the following:

```
    FILE *ifp = fopen ("myfile.txt", "r"),      /* infile pointer */
         *ofp = fopen ("tokenfile.txt", "w");   /* outfile pointer */
```

(I'm not that creative, I just use `ifp` for the *input file pointer* and `ofp` for the *output file pointer*)

Whenever you open a file, **before** you attempt to read or write to the file, you must **validate** that the file is actually open for reading or writing (e.g. `fopen` succeeded). For example:

```
    if (ifp == NULL) {  /* validate input open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-myfile.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    if (ofp == NULL) {  /* validate output open for writing */
        perror ("fopen-tokenfile.txt");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now with both files open, you can call `istoken` and read from `ifp`. However, this takes modifying `istoken` to take a `FILE *` parameter for use with `fscanf` instead of using `scanf`. For example:

```
/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken (FILE *ifp, char *word) {

    while (fscanf(ifp, "%1023s", word) == 1)    /* valid read take place? */
        if (*word == '<')                       /* is 1st char '<' ? */
            return true;                        /* return true */

    return false;                               /* out of words */
}
```

After the return of `istoken`, you can write to `stdout` to let the user know if a token was found and also write to `ofp` to store token in your output file, e.g..

```
    if (istoken (ifp, word)) {  /* call istoken passing open ifp */
        printf ("found token: '%s'\n", word);   /* output token */
        fprintf (ofp, "%s\n", word); /* write token to outfile */
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no token found.\n");
```

Lastly, you must `fclose` the files you have open. **But there is a twist** for files you **write** to. You should **validate** the `fclose` to insure a stream-error did not occur on `ofp` that may not have been otherwise caught. e.g.

```
    fclose (ifp);           /* close infile pointer */

    if (fclose(ofp) == EOF) /* validate "close-after-write" */
        perror ("stream error on outfile stream close");
```

Putting it altogether, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXC 1024

/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken (FILE *ifp, char *word) {

    while (fscanf(ifp, "%1023s", word) == 1)    /* valid read take place? */
        if (*word == '<')                       /* is 1st char '<' ? */
            return true;                        /* return true */

    return false;                               /* out of words */
}

int main (void) {

    char word[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *ifp = fopen ("myfile.txt", "r"),      /* infile pointer */
         *ofp = fopen ("tokenfile.txt", "w");   /* outfile pointer */

    if (ifp == NULL) {  /* validate input open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-myfile.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    if (ofp == NULL) {  /* validate output open for writing */
        perror ("fopen-tokenfile.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    if (istoken (ifp, word)) {  /* call istoken passing open ifp */
        printf ("found token: '%s'\n", word);   /* output token */
        fprintf (ofp, "%s\n", word); /* write token to outfile */
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no token found.\n");

    fclose (ifp);           /* close infile pointer */

    if (fclose(ofp) == EOF) /* validate "close-after-write" */
        perror ("stream error on outfile stream close");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat myfile.txt
my dog has <too> many fleas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanftoken
found token: '<too>'

$ cat tokenfile.txt
<too>
```

The best advice I can give you on learning C is to simply *slow down*. There is a lot to learn, and in fact given 30 years, I have barely scratched the surface (that and they keep revising the standard every so often). Just take it a step at a time. Loop up the `man page` for each function you use, find out what the proper parameter are and most critically what it returns and what form of error reporting is has (e.g. does it set `errno` so you can use `perror` to report the error or do you need to use `fprintf (stderr, ....)`?

Always enable *compiler warnings* and read and understand the warning and **do not accept code until it compiles without warning**. You can learn a lot of C just by listening to what your compiler is telling you. And if all else fails... talk to the duck. [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), really, it helps `:)`

Comment: how can I check to see if it is returning true for my token words?

Comment: Hold on, I'll drop an example.

Comment: ` bool istoken(char word[]) {

    while (scanf("%100s", word) == 1) {
        
        if (word[MAX_LEN] == '<') {
            printf("the token is: %s\n", word);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} `   This is what I have and I don't think it is working because its not printing the token word for the printf statement and my program just kinda pauses so nothing ever is exucuted I guess. @david

Comment: If you put `backticks` around your code in the comment, it will format as code `:)`. Your code with `MAX_LEN` mucks it up. `if (*word == '<')` is the same as `if (word[0] == '<'`) not `MAX_LEN` (unless, of course, `MAX_LEN = 0`) If you change `MAX_LEN` to zero (`0`) -- then your proposed function is fine - as long as you, at minimum, defined `char word[101] = "";` in your caller. `:)`

Comment: I have char word just defined as `char word[MAX_LEN]` why is that not right? `#define MAX_LEN 100` is above my main function.

Comment: @StacyWillis - No, no... Say it ain't so, but *"How are your providing your input on `stdin`?"* (**note:** how I pipe the input to my example. If your input is in a **file** you will need to redirect the file to your program (e.g. for my example name it would be `./bin/scanftoken < filename`)

Comment: @StacyWillis `char word[MAX_LEN]` is RIGHT, just NOT, in `if (word[MAX_LEN] == '<')`. Your `char word[MAX_LEN];` which you should *initialize* to all *nul* with `char word[MAX_LEN] = "";` is the **declaration** of your array. You do not thereafter use `MAX_LEN` as an index because it will be **outside your array bounds by `1`** (arrays are indexed `0 -> n-1` in C.) If you want the last character in `word` then `size_t len = strlen(word);` then `char last = word[len];`.

Comment: You lost me. My input is a file. I have an in file ('r')  and an out file ('w') files opened. My input file is an 'r' file and I wrote a function to copy it to a 'w' file. so I'm confused by what you mean by `./bin/scanftoken < filename`

Comment: Let's find you again. If you have a `file`, you will open the file in your caller and pass a `FILE *fp` file pointer as a parameter to your `istoken` function and then use `while (fscanf (fp, "%s", word) == 1)`, not `scanf` (which reads from `stdin`) Now `stdin` is a file-stream, it is file-descriptor Zero and has a constant defined for it as `STDIN_FILENO`. You can read from your file without your `"r"` by redirecting the file to `stdin` (e.g. `cat file | ./program` or `./program <file`, the 2nd being the proper way. Do you need a file example too?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful thank you. would my parameter be my input file or my output file?

Comment: Do you want to write to the output file from within `istoken` as you do with your `printf` statement or would you like to write the token to the output file from `main()` as I do in my example?

Comment: The token to the output file from `main()` like in your example.

Comment: @David C. Rankin A lot of what you're typing looks like Linux shell commands. Are you sure she's on Linux?

Comment: `/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken(char word[], FILE* in) {

    while (fscanf(in,"%s", word) == 1) {
        if (word[0] == '<') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}` this is what I have and then in main I have `if (istoken(word, in)) {
        printf("the token found is: %s\n", word);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(in, "error\n");
    }` and It didn't work

Comment: @Zebrafish - we are doing a file I/O example as well. Redirection works fine on windoze too `:)`

Comment: Okay this is what I got and it just returns false and my program ends.   `/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken(FILE* in, char word[]) {

    while (fscanf(in, "%1023s", word) == 1) {
        if (word[0] == '<') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}`     and then in main I have                                                                      `if (istoken(in, word)) {
        printf("the token found is: %s\n", word);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(in, "error\n");
    }
    
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: OK -- where do you ever do any output with `fprintf (out, ...` ? Also, what do you think happens when you try and write `"error\n"` to your **input** file? Doesn't `"r"` mean **open for reading**? How does `fprintf(in, "error\n"); ` work? (those are rhetorical *"hints"* by the way `:)` The *take it step-by-step* advice for C, really means just that, take it line-by-line, parameter-by-paramter, character-by-character. It is that level of detail that C requires. It is exact. You are learning to *Program* in C, in other languages, you just learn a language.

Comment: @StacyWillis Is the fog beginning to lift? Do you understand why the proposed code in your comment isn't doing what you want it to?

Comment: That makes sense to change it to out instead of in, but it is still not working. It doesn't ever return true so something is wrong in my bool function. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Edit your question and ADD your current code at the end (don't change your original question or none of the questions or comments will make sense any more). I'll take a look. In the mean time, I want you to copy/paste my code into a new file on your computer and compile and convince yourself it really does work -- then it's just a matter of finding where your trail fell off the track. I have a few errands to run, so it will be an hour or so before I can sit back down and look at this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mind using some powerful lexical analyzer, I suggest you using `flex` which can help you lot for tokenization.

As you can see, [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) let you write token pattern and generate a `C` parser which does all the work.

[image: FLEX]

> Here is a program which compresses multiple blanks and tabs down to a single blank, and throws away whitespace found at the end of a line:

```
%%
[ \t]+        putchar( ' ' );
[ \t]+$       /* ignore this token */
```

You can find more at http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/flex.html.